# Исправить метки, связанные с flash

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

В основном метка [flash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash) прикрепляется к вопросам об Adobe Flash, но попадаются также и о flash-памяти:

- [Как в Atmel Studio 6 разместить массив во flash памяти?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/354727)
- [Как в VirtualBox сделать boot c usb флешки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/348463)

Предлагаю всем вопросам по Adobe Flash назначать метку [flash-player](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash-player) или синоним [flashvideo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flashvideo), а метку [flash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash) впредь назначать вопросам по flash-памяти. Внести соответствующие изменения в описание метки [flash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash).

Comment: @NickVolynkin имхо, вместо коммента стоило к правке описание добавить соответствующее.

Comment: @alexolut я подозреваю, что эти описания никто не читает. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin не читают, потому что их никто не пишет :)

Comment: @alexolut согласен, что здесь может быть проблема курицы и яйца. Точно помню, что я писал эти комментарии, когда делал предлагаемые правки, и что читаю их, когда проверяю такие правки. Но когда это ограничение снимается, пьянящий дух свободы заставляет забыть о комментариях. )

Answer (score 6):

Насколько я вижу, большинство существующих вопросов с меткой [flash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash) относятся именно к Adobe Flash, и это соответствует текущему описанию метки. Более того, так как сайт посвящён программированию, т.е. по большей части именно программам, а не железу, вопросов по flash-памяти будет ожидаемо меньше, чем по Adobe Flash. Ещё можно обратить внимание на аналогичную [метку](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash) на enSO. Где речь тоже идет про Adobe, а для flash-памяти используется метка [flash-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash-memory).

Короче говоря, мне кажется наиболее правильным и простым вариантом будет добавление метки [flash-память](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c) для вопросов по железу. А имеющуюся метку оставить за вопросами по Adobe.

Answer (score 2):

Перебрал вопросы по метке [flash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash). Где было нужно, поменял метку на [flash-память](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c).

В процессе родилась метка [live-usb](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/live-usb):

> Вопросы о создании и работе с подключаемыми носителями данных, с которых возможна загрузка операционной системы.

Comment: Русифицировать не будем? :)

Comment: @alexolut я бы не стал, но можно сделать синоним.

Comment: Понять бы еще какой. "Загрузочная флешка"?

Comment: @alexolut там и HDD может быть. "Загрузочный носитель"?

Comment: "Bootable device", ну да, вполне. Надо же что-то такое, что будут пытаться набирать в строке ввода меток. А не синтетический синоним. Еще было бы хорошо знать, какую метку ставит участник до того как она заменяется на основной синоним. Для статистики так сказать.

Comment: @alexolut  статистика автозамены меток  есть на странице синонимов. Разумеется, чтобы ее собрать, сначала нужно синонимы назначить.

Comment: @alexolut вообще, мне даже больше нравится "загрузочный носитель". Я бы его выбрал центральной меткой.

Comment: Так выбирайте. У Вас же есть полномочия :)